# Populate a datagrid from another datagrid in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

As mentionned in the title, I try to populate a datagrid from data of another one. Basically, The first datagrid is populated from the active directory.  I do some operations on these datas, and I would like to make a report of these operations (Passed or failed).
I'd like this report in another datagrid in another winform.
As my operations is to delete parts of the datas I get in my firt datagrid, I cannot populate the second one the same way it works for the first one
So I'd like to get the datas from the first datagrid, add them to another datagrid in the second form, add a column 'Status' and populate it with the results of my operations.
Is there a way to 'copy' the first datagrid ?  Is there a best practice to do this kind of job ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course there could be many possible ways, but that came to my mind is.
You know the number of columns, so make a `list` of class(corresponding to your fields). Extract the cell data from `datagrid` and populate the list with the entries (if all required). Import this list to the other form. Set `Datasource`of datagrid equal to list and refresh.